# How can I make adsense appear on my website again?

Tags: web, adsense

I have just developed this website: www.hackit4me.com and I tried to add adsense to it (today). My adsense account is prety old (three years old), but it does not show up on the website as you can see. Is there anything I can do to fix this problem? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: I have been trying to fix this problem for two hours now.

Comment: The ads show up here.

Answer (score 0):

The ads can become inactive after not using them for such a long period.Try to make a new ad unit, paste the code to your site where ever you want and wait for at least 2-3 days for them to become active.
You can check whether the ads are active or not, in Adsense Dashbaord->my ad units and filter them with date created.